# C# Dynamic Regular Expression where comparison string might have predictable variations

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Trying to dynamically match a string against a list of strings to find a match, but the input might have slight variations.

**The only two variations are " " and "-" (space and hyphen)**

Here's an example:

List of titles;

Trying to match "BK III" in list of titles, but in the title, it could be represented as "BKIII" or "BK-III"

If I do something like the following, it works well when there's an exact match, but I'm trying to account for the slight variation

```
string escapedModelNumber = Regex.Escape(product.ToLower());
string pattern = $@"\b{escapedModelNumber}\b";              

foreach (string s in titles)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to understand what the variations might be, and then insert a regex into the `product` name to account for them (*after* escaping). For example, for `BK III` you might change that to `BK[ -]?III`

Comment: Updated the post to outline the only two possible variations, space and hyphen.

Comment: @DanielD: are you sure about that, I see _Trying to match "BK III" in list of titles, but in the title, it could be represented as "BKIII" or "BK-III"_, which to me reads "the separator may be a space, a hyphen or ellided".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you do not need to to use `product.ToLower()` since matching can be made case insensitive with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` or just putting `(?i)` inline modifier into the regex itself.

Next, if you do not know - since your regex is dynamic - where the `-` or space can appear in the searched term, AND these characters include a SPACE character (so, we cannot remove spaces from the input string as we'll lose word boundary positions), **you may add optional space/hyphen in between each of the `product` chars**.

**Note also**, that since you are using `Regex.Escape` and never know if the `product` starts/ends with special characters, **you cannot rely on `\b`**, use *adaptive word boundaries*, `(?!\B\w)`.

```cs
string escapedModelNumber = string.Join("[ -]?", product.ToCharArray().Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString())));
string pattern = $@"(?i)(?!\B\w){escapedModelNumber}(?!\B\w)";
```

Now, your pattern will look like

```
(?i)(?!\B\w)B[ -]?K[ -]?I[ -]?I[ -]?I(?!\B\w)
```

and it will be case insensitive, and will match the product as a whole word if there are word characters at the start/end of the product name (else, the word boundaries will be ignored) and there will be a match even if there is a space or `-` in between the product name characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the only variations are  , `-` or neither of them, you can modify the `escapedModelNumber` to account for those variations:

```cs
String product = "BK III";
String[] titles = { "product BKIII", "product Bk III", "product BK-III", "product BKII" };
String escapedModelNumber = Regex.Escape(product);
String variableModelNumber = Regex.Replace(escapedModelNumber, @"\\ |-", "[ -]*");
String pattern = $@"\b{variableModelNumber}\b";
foreach (String s in titles) {
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, pattern, product, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
}
```

Output:

```
product BK III
product BK III
product BK III
product BKII
```

Demo on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/mdb8Hn)

Note that since you are using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, there is no need to convert `product` to lowercase.